# Why do we have to resize the array when reading the image?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
IMG_SIZE = 50
traing_data =[]
def create_training_data():
    for c in categories:
        path = os.path.join(dir,c)
        class_num = categories.index(c)  # dog =0, cat =1
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
                traing_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass # Some photos are broken
            
              
create_training_data()      



X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
y = np.array(y)
```

Hi guys! I was studying convolutional neural network from youtube and I was wondering why do I have to resize the image array ( new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE)) ) and the X array ( X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1) ) ?

Comment: Most `neural-network`s are designed to work with fixed size input, for further explanation see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64022/why-must-a-cnn-have-fixed-input-size

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: About the second reshaping, from (nr_samples, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE) to (nr_samples, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1): the reason for it is to add the channel dimension to the image data, which is often needed when working with images using some of the DL libraries (e.g. Keras). When images are RGB, the channel dimension is already there (3), but when loading grayscale images this dimension isn't there (because it's 1).